# How to run the IBM MQSI commands using Java?

Tags: java, ibm-integration-bus

Need some help on this.

My requirement is to start, stop the message flows of IBM MQ using Java.
For example, I can see the MQSI command like `mqsistopmsgflow` to stop the message flow.

But is there any API available in IBM AllClient Java library to execute the same command or any other way to that in Java?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're mixing up MQSI (now known as App Connect Enterprise) with MQ. Message Flows and their administration are nothing to do with MQ.

Comment: ok, thanks for your reply.

Comment: Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mqsistopmsgflow XYZ");

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the IBM Integration API.  This is documented in the IBM Integration Bus 10 Knowledge center page "[Product overview>IBM Integration Bus technical overview>The IBM Integration Bus environment>IBM Integration API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/be43410_.htm)":

> The IBM® Integration API is a remote programming interface that your custom integration applications can use to control integration nodes and their resources.

> The IBM Integration API consists solely of a Java™ implementation. Your custom integration applications have complete access to the integration node functions and resources through the set of Java classes that constitute the IBM Integration API.

> Use the IBM Integration API to interact with the integration node to
>   perform the following tasks:
>
> - Inquire and ***set the status of*** the integration node and ***its associated resources***, and be informed if the status of any of following items changes:
>
>   - Deployed message flows

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I can see the below methods from BrokerProxy class which has methods like 

stopMessageFlows()
Description: Asks the broker to stop all message flows that exist on the broker.

However, I could not find the method where I can start/start the given message flow from the required execution group(Integration server)

Please let me know if you have any idea on this.

Thanks,
Venkata

Comment: You have to use the [MessageFlowProxy](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.cmp.doc/com/ibm/broker/config/proxy/MessageFlowProxy.html). In its API documentation you see how to get an instance of this class.

Comment: This is very helpful and able to start/stop message flows.       Thank you, Daniel.

Comment: @Ven_QA if you found my answer helpful please accept.   I linked to the main page in the knowledge center,  from there you can get to all the documentation for all methods including MessageFlowProxy.